# How to disable highlights on QDateEdit PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

I have this code below where I created a QDateEdit widget, and when I ran it the it focuses or highlights the texts in the widget. is there a chance I can disable it so that it can't be mistakenly edited?

```
self.date = QDateEdit(calendarPopup=True)
self.date.clearFocus()
self.date.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
self.date.lineEdit()
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You're already disabling editing using `setReadOnly(True)`, so what do you want to disable? The arrows? Besides, what would be the point of a QDateEdit if the user cannot *edit* it? Just use a read only QLineEdit.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right and you want to actually disable it, you can do so by setting its `setEnabled` property to `False`. This is done through the following code;

```
self.date.setEnabled(False)
```

Comment: This will work. But one drawback is that everything will be grayed out. To get around that, you can edit the styleSheet property to get the border and text back to black: `QDateEdit:disabled{color: black; border: 1px solid black; }` . You also might want to set buttonSymbols to NoButtons to hide the up/down arrows.

Comment: @bfris that will only work as long as the current style *does* use black for text and a light color as `Base`; a more appropriate solution should be to use `palette(text)`.